# square of an operator on hilbert space $A:H\to H$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Given an operator $A:H \to H$ when $H$ is a Hilbert space, how the square of operator is defined?
$A^2=AA^*$ or $A=AA$?

Comment: The square is the square. $AA^*$ is the square of $\lvert A\rvert$.

Comment: @tomasz What do you mean by $|A|$ in the case when $A$ is a linear operator?

Comment: I guess that he meant $\sqrt{A^2}$

Comment: i meant $\sqrt{AA^*}$ (although $\lvert A\rvert$ might as well mean $\sqrt{A^*A}$, depending on what you prefer; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any suitable algebraic structure (most generally - a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) or multiplicative [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup), in your case - algebra of linear operators) a square of an element $A$ means $A^2 = A \cdot A$.